# Ubuntu 16.04 xerox travel scanner 100 will not calibrate, gives black images

Tags: usb, scanner

**OS**: Ubuntu 16.04
**Device**: Xerox Travel Scanner 100.

**Problems**
a):  Output is always a black page.
b):  Researching the a) problem indicates that calibration is required
             - unable to calibrate.

**System Info**

sane-find-scanner finds the device:

```
*found USB scanner (vendor=0x04a7 [Xerox], product=0x04ac [Travel Scanner 100], chip=GL842) at libusb:001:004*
```

scanimage -L gives:

```
*device `genesys:libusb:001:004' is a Xerox Travelscanner 100 flatbed scanner*
```

Several online search results for this issue indicated that the device needs calibration.  I do not have the original calibration sheet, and Xerox does not sell/ship them, but in desperation I printed one from a web search and tried feeding it to:

```
scanimage --calibrate >xerox.cal
```

After the scanner buzzed and brrr'ed its way through the page, that command gave:

```
*scanimage: setting of option --calibrate failed (Operation not supported)*
```

But a print of the available options for the device shows it as a valid option.

The scanner goes through all the motions to scan a page, but produces a black output image.  I have tried Simplescan, Xsane, gScan2pdf, scanimage and even installed Skanlite to no avail.  The result is always a black image. It seems to me this is an issue with the genesys backend. Or, it is something so glaringly obvious that I'm missing it.

The device works properly on Windows XP (yes XP).  I'm trying to move to Linux, but keep running into these gotchas, so I've kept the Windows partition.

I tried scanning from a LiveUSB "vanilla" Ubuntu, thinking that I might have messed up something with all the removes/installs.  Same result:  black image.

Does anyone have a solution or a suggestion for fixing this?

Comment: Update:  the "--calibrate" is a "button"; I tried using gScan2PDF's button in the GUI, got a number of seconds of whirring, then a black image.

Comment: I managed to download libsane-genesys-1.0.23 and libsane-1.0.23 and modified the links to use them.  The scan results were mediocre, but legible.  The output contained prominent vertical banding and there was a grey hue to the page.  So, I decided to work around the issue entirely, and installed Windows XP in a virtual box.  I then installed the original driver and scan app, and can now scan properly.